# What is better css selector practice: Using multiple element or using one id/class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What is better using Alt A `header nav ul li a {color: red}` or Alt B `.nav-link {color:red}`?

The pros for Alt a is that i don't need to introduce any more css id/classes, but it is more prone to specificity war than alt B.
Check out jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/43znf/1/

Comment: You should use whatever best describes your HTML structure.

Comment: I would give your anchor tag a class name and target that class.

Comment: The code in your post and the code in the jsfiddle are quite different in that here you use an ID and there you use a class in Alt B. Instinctively I would refrain from using an ID on a link, and I would rather use a class on a parent like the `ul` in this case. But I can't justify it absoluteley.

Comment: If you use a selector that minimally identifies the set of elements that you want the style rule to apply to, you will find that specificity is your friend, not your enemy.

Answer (score 1):

This really is subjective.  When I first learned I did everything using Alt A, but now I do a mix of A and B.  Alt A will apply the style to every `<header> <nav> <ul> <li> <a>` nested element, meaning that if you have multiple sections that match this nest pattern they will be styled in the designated way.  When you use Alt B, you have to apply the class / id to a certain element, meaning that you can pick and choose which nested `<a>` tag will receive the style.

Bottom line, it really is not practical to just code in Alt A or Alt B.  I would recommend using a little of each.

EDIT:  If you plan on getting a job where HTML / CSS editing is required, your boss may have a certain way he or she wants it done.  Just some heads up.

EDIT 2: It's also a good idea to know when it's the appropriate time to use an ID and when a Class should be used. ID's should only be used once in a document, classes can be used multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how versatile you want your CSS to be. If you have a single element that you want styled or just a handful, use the id or class. However, using Alt A will allow you to add new elements without necessarily having to assign the id/class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use both and both have valid use cases in real life. 
When you have an element that is unique and sure that its styles need not be used anywhere else you could make use of id for simplicity.

eg: Header section of your website "template" or "layout" which remains same and probably you would not reuse the styles.

But when you have to style an element say a form button, you have to use a css class, as the form button will be used many a times as you would see.

Using classes can be elegant in that if you  stick to the principles. Do not overstyle an element using a single class. Split the rules in an intelligent manner so that each class can be used somewhere else. Try to avoid writing context specific rules in a class which will block you from inheriting the class.